# Как преобразовать IEnumerable<JToken> в Linq.JToken

Tags: c#, json, asp.net, linq

У меня есть JObject. После выборки не могу преобразовать в JToken

```
JToken cliObj = jObject["data"].Where(x => x["systemCode"].ToString() == "SD")
```

Comment: какой результат ты ожидаешь?

Comment: Найденного элемента надо преобразовать в JToken или JOBject

Answer (score 1):

Метод [`Where`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.7.2) возвращает коллекцию элементов подходящих под условие.

Если нужен только один элемент нужно воспользоваться другими методами, например [`First`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.first?view=netframework-4.7.2)